# react-bootstrap SCSS theme orerride not working

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, react-bootstrap

**Index.tsx:**

```
import './index.scss';
```

**Top of index.scss:**

```
@import './scss/main.scss';
```

**main.scss**

```
@import './custom';
```

**_custom.scss**

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #ff0000,
  "danger": #ff4136
);
```

**Login.tsx**

```
<div className="card">
    <div className="card-body">
        <h5 className="card-title">Login</h5>
        <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Log in</h6>
        <Form>
            <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
                <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
                <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                Submit
            </Button>
        </Form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Yet, the primary color hasn't changed:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't `_custom.css` be named as `custom.scss`? Are there any special cases of Sass compiler regarding CSS files starting with underscore? It sould have an `.scss` extension instead of `.css` for to Sass compiler actually parse it. Also, try to move the `$theme-colors:(...)` declaration before including `@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try it using this approach here;

in local bootstrap load Scss, see live project [Codesandbox typescript react](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-dream-0wkdn?file=/src/App.tsx)

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap-overrides" /*your overwrite variables/files*/
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/code";
.
.
. // rest of file/function
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use variables like `$theme-colors` inside a `css` file

You named your file ***_custom.css*** try to rename it for ***_custom.scss***

Comment: That was a typo, it is already an scss file

Comment: So if your file doesn't apply the changes, it is probably an importation / naming problem, check you architecture. Or else you could try to check if it's about the weight of your selector, check on your console if you can see the css or not at all.